# Add dynamic Components to ViewChildren

Tags: angular

Currently, I can dynamically load a single component and display it in a ViewChild like this:

```
@Component({
   selector: '...',
   template: '<ng-container #viewRef></ng-container>'
})
export class SomeComponent {
@ViewChild('viewRef', {read: ViewContainerRef}) public viewRef;

  constructor(private compiler: Compiler) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(SomeModule).then((factory) =>  {
      this.componentRef = this.placeholder.createComponent(factory);
    });
  }
}
```

Now I would like to load multiple Components and display them dynamically in a list. `ViewChildren` should be the solution to this. The problem is, `ViewChildren` does not allow to add new elements or create them similar to `createComponent` on `ViewChild`.

How can I create dynamic components and add them to `ViewChildren`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use ViewChildren to get the QueryList of elements or directives from the view DOM. Any time a child element is added, removed, or moved, the query list will be updated, and the changes observable of the query list will emit a new value. That means that you can create a subscription on your `viewRefs.changes` event and load components dynamically using [ComponentFactoryResolver](https://v5.angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver). See the example below:

```
export class SomeComponent {
    @ViewChildren('viewRef', {read: ViewContainerRef})
    public viewRefs: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;

    constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.viewRefs.changes.subscribe((list: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>) => {
            list.forEach((viewRef: ViewContainerRef, index: number) => {
                const componentFactory: ComponentFactory<any> = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(OtherComponent);
                viewRef.createComponent(componentFactory, index);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This works as expected, thank you! I'm just not a 100% sure to what i actually subscribe. When is `changes` triggered?

Comment: Any time a child element is added, removed, or moved, the query list will be updated, and the changes observable of the query list will emit a new value.

Comment: But that would also mean that each dynamic component in viewChildren is replaced with a new one, as soon as something is added/removed from the List correct?

Comment: Correct. All dynamic components are gathered into list. You subscribe to any changes in that list and the emmited value is a new list containing actual state of child components